# What are <> and n$ in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

What do this "<>" and n$ do in VBA?

For example if I have the follow code:

```
  If ThisWorkbook.Path <> Application.StartupPath And Dir(Application.StartupPath & "\" & "1006.xls") = "" Then
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("StartUp").Copy
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs (Application.StartupPath & "\" & "1006.xls")
    n$ = ActiveWorkbook.Name
    ActiveWindow.Visible = False
    Workbooks("1006.xls").Save
    Workbooks(n$).Close (False)
  End If
```

Answer (score 4):

<> is an inequality operator

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/215yacb6(v=vs.80).aspx

Isn't the $ at the end of a variable to define it as a string variable?  I think that is older style

Comment: don't you have to declare a variable before you use it? or does the $ sign already declares it as string? I can't search these on google as it get escaped..

Comment: If there is no `Option Explicit` at the top of the script, you can use a variable without declaring it.

Comment: I think this will give you the reference you are looking for to add to Adam's comment http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/y9341s4f(v=VS.80).aspx

Answer (score 3):

In `n$` the `$` forces the variable `n` to be  `String`

`<>` is `not equal`

Comment: you only have to if you are using `Option Explicit`